# How to allow bash to performantly read data which includes NUL bytes?

Tags: bash, binary, byte, nul

More exactly, the question is:

**Which recipes are there to enable `bash` scripts to properly and safely process `N` bytes which might contain `NUL`?**

This question led to following observation:

```
bash -c 'LC_ALL=C read -rN 1 </dev/zero'
```

- Tested with Debian 10's `bash` version `5.0.17(1)-release`

([I tried to find out myself but found no pointer why this happens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67534890/490291)).  All I found out so far is, that "my" `bash` apparently skips all `NUL` bytes on `read -N`.

A possible workaround in the special case with `-N 1` is to use

```
LC_ALL=C IFS= read -rd '' -n 1
```

such that `NUL` acts as delimiter, so `read` returns.  But this trick fails in case you want to skip over more than 1 byte, as then the `read` terminates after the first `NUL` seen.

For special cases there are workarounds, like forking off `dd`, but if you want to process the data in `bash` or need to often skip just a few bytes, forking hurts more than it helps.

Also looping over `read -d '' -n 1` is cumbersome if you want to skip over bigger `NUL` areas, because this is one syscall per byte.

Notes:

- This is not a question about opinions which solution is best.
- This is a question to list ways to handle the most common cases.
- And the answers should be applicable to use cases like:

  - Pipes, where you cannot seek
  - Sockets (like `<>"/dev/tcp/$HOST/$PORT"`)

Please always keep in mind that "performance" includes more than just raw speed.  It often includes the time you need to change something, where rewriting things from scratch takes too long, or plugging in something like `dd` gets extremely difficult.  Quite often all you have is just pure `bash`.  Plus some helpers.

For example there might be some bigger script which is applied to something like `git fast-export`.  This script works perfectly, until the first binary with a `NUL` byte is added to the repo.  Suddenly `read -N` goes out of sync, such that `git fast-import` complains.  If the code is used mainly to edit commit messages (which are treated like the binary data) you have to duplicat your code:  One for binary, NUL aware, one for commits, to change in bash.

Probably here is no such thing like one size fits all, so we likely need more solutions than to just call `dd`.

Answer (score 1):

Following solves it for me in the situation, where `bash` is talking to a pipe.

Instead of using `producer | bashscript | consumer` I put some transformation script into the pipe:

```
producer | encoder | bashscript | decoder | consumer
```

- The `encoder` escapes `00` into `01 02` and `01` into `01 03`.
- The `decoder` unescapes `00` from `01 02` and `01` from `01 03`.

Then, in `bash` I can use following routine to read `N` bytes:

```
: readbytes N variable
readbytes()
{
local -n ___var="${2:-REPLY}"
local ___esc ___tmp
LC_ALL=C read -rN "$1" ___var || return     # short read
___esc="$___var"
while   ___esc="${___esc//[^$'\x01']/}"
        ___tmp="${#___esc}"
        [ 0 -lt "$___tmp" ]
do
        ___esc=
        LC_ALL=C read -rN "$___tmp" ___esc
        ___tmp=$?
        ___var="$___var$___esc"
        [ 0 = $___tmp ] || return $___tmp   # short read
done
return 0
}
```

What does this routine do?

- A call to `readbytes N variable` first reads `N` bytes into `variable`
- Then it counts the `01`-bytes (`\1`)
- Each of the `01`-bytes have a second byte, hence we are the given count short.
- So read this additional count and append it to the `variable`.
- Now, again, additional `01`-bytes might have shown up, so we need to re-read them, too.
- This loop thus terminates in at most `ld N` steps
- So this routine has at most `O(ld N)` syscalls compared to `O(N)` with `read -n`.  When `00`- and `01`-bytes are absent, this routine only does 1 syscall.
- And the overall pessimistic runtime complexity is somewhat like `O(N ld N)` which is not perfect but much better than `O(N*N)` when using `read -n`

Notes:

- This routine does not decode the data.  So if you read 10 byte and there is one `NUL` in it, you will get back a string of 11 bytes (with `NUL` replaced by the byte sequence `01 02` from the encoder).
- The decoder is not always needed, as `bash` is perfectly suited to write `NUL` bytes with something like `printf '\0'` or `printf %b '\0'`.  However if you mostly copy STDIN to STDOUT while changing a few things, most time it is more convenient not to convert the data within `bash` and leave that to the decoder.
- There probably is no good way to decode the data in `bash`, as `bash` variables (like all environment variables) cannot contain `NUL`.

Here is an [encoder in Python3](https://github.com/hilbix/bashnul/blob/master/encode.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
while 1:
    a = sys.stdin.buffer.read(102400);
    if not a: break
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(a.replace(b'\1', b'\1\3').replace(b'\0', b'\1\2'))
```

And the [decoder in Python3](https://github.com/hilbix/bashnul/blob/master/decode.py) which only is a bit more complex:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
dang = False
while 1:
    a   = sys.stdin.buffer.read(102400);
    if not a: break
    if dang:
        a   = b'\1'+a
        dang    = False
    if a[-1] == 1:
        dang    = True
        a   = a[:-1]
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(a.replace(b'\1\2', b'\0').replace(b'\1\3', b'\1'))
```

The [complete `git` repo on GitHub](https://github.com/hilbix/bashnul) also contains a C code wrapper `bashnul`, which runs much faster than the Python code (also the C program detects encoding errors etc.).

(Beware, it's not throroughly tested.)